# How does this glob expression remove colons?

Tags: wildcards, pattern-matching

Say we have a file called "Hello World: The easiest program" and its name is saved in a variable called "title".

I want to match this with glob pattern matching, but remove the colon. In other words, I want it to match "Hello World The easiest program"

I found out you can do this by using the following:

`${/:/|${title}|}`

It works, but I don't understand why.

I know that "|" is OR, so to me it looks like it matches "${/:/}" or "${${title}}" or "${}", none of which look like they're removing the colon.

So my question is: How/why does the glob pattern matching expression above remove colons from a title?

Edit: I should mention the shell I'm using is the Steam ROM Manager. And it seems I was mistaken and it's not a glob expression, but a Steam ROM Parser function variable that optionally uses glob syntax (in place of the default regex syntax).Thanks Steeldiver and ilkkachu!

Comment: what shell are you using? It seems that `${/:/|${title}|}` doesn't work for my current shells (`bash` and `zsh`)

Comment: Could you give a full example of this?

Comment: I am using the Steam ROM Manager on Steam Deck. I didn't understand that the thing between the forward slashes will be replaced.

Comment: Parser Type in Steam ROM Manager was set to Glob.

With Hack Saws help, I was now able to use this knowledge to remove brackets, parentheses, their contents and any whitespaces before or after using:

`${/(\s?\[.*?\]\s?)/|${/(\s?\(.*?\)\s?)/|${/:/|${title}|}|}`

It first takes the title, replaces colons with nothing, then takes the result and replaces the first thing that matches `\s?\(.*?\)\s?` and replaces it with nothing and then takes the result again and replaces the first thing that matches `\s?\[.*?\]\s?` and replaces it with nothing

Comment: The Steam ROM Manager seems hardly a common Unix-y shell, so in the least you really should [edit] your question to include that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, assuming you have `title="Hello World: The easiest program"`,
if you use **Parameter Expansion** like this:

```
echo ${title/:/}
```

It will print out

```
Hello World The easiest program
```

`${title/:/}` says "take the parameter title, but the first time there is a ':', sub in a ''." (That is, nothing)

If you use an extra /, like this: `${title//:/}` it will substitute all of them.

```
title="Hello World: The easiest:::::: program"
echo ${title//:/}
Hello World The easiest program
```

With an obvious substitution:

```
title="Hello World: The easiest:::::: program"
echo ${title//:/*}
Hello World* The easiest****** program
```

Answer (score 3):

The expression in your question is not a *glob expression*, it's apparently a [Steam ROM Parser function variable](https://github.com/SteamGridDB/steam-rom-manager/blob/master/src/lang/english/markdown/parser-variables.md#function-variables) that *optionally* uses glob syntax (in place of the default regex syntax) for its pattern matching sequence.

The expression is of the form

```
${/pattern/|input|}
```

with `pattern` equal to `:` and `input` equal to variable expansion `${title}`. In this context `|` is to be read as a kind of ternary conditional

```
|on match|no match(optional)
```

So `${/:/|${title}|}` means to match occurences of `:` in `${title}` and replace them with nothing.

Note that since `:` is not special in either shell glob or regular expression syntax, it shouldn't actually matter whether you set the `Parser Type` to `glob` or otherwise.